# Nested ForEach Knockout 2.2.1 doesn't show up to 4th level

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out on a MVC/Durandal/Knockout project why i can't bind a 
`ContractsList() = ko.observableArray();`  into a 4th level foreach.
It works fine until 3rd level.

Here is the Json that I trying to bind.

```
    {"Contracts":
        {
            "Contract":
                    [  
                        {
                            "NrContract":null,
                            "IdStore":"5",
                            "FlagStatus":"P",
                            "Date":"30/11/2017",                        
                            "Sale":"3168.23",                       
                            "DsName":"TEST1",                       
                            "Items":
                                { 
                                    "Item":
                                    [
                                        {"NrItems":"1","VlTotalItems":"1112.23","DsItems":"3123123"},
                                        {"NrItems":"1","VlTotalItems":"2056","DsItems":"bbb"}
                                    ]
                                }
                        },
                        {   
                            "NrContract":null,
                            "IdStore":"5",
                            "FlagStatus":"P",
                            "Date":"30/11/2017",                        
                            "DsName":"TEST2",                       
                            "Items":
                                {   
                                    "Item":[
                                                {"NrItems":"7","VlTotalItems":"7785,61","DsItems":"3123123"},
                                                {"NrItems":"1","VlTotalItems":"3","DsItems":"oi"}
                                            ]
                                }
                        }
                    ]
        }
    }
```

foreach simplified:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: ContractsList'>
    <div data-bind='foreach: Contract'>
        <div data-bind='foreach: Items'>    
            <div data-bind='foreach: Item'>
                <span data-bind='text: DsItems'></span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `Items` is an object, not an array. Use `Items.Item` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `items` is an object not an array:

```
"Items":
    {   
        "Item":[
                    {"NrItems":"7","VlTotalItems":"7785,61","DsItems":"3123123"},
                    {"NrItems":"1","VlTotalItems":"3","DsItems":"oi"}
                ]
    }
```

Update to array and this will work if its a mistake or

```
<div data-bind='foreach: Items.Item'>
    <span data-bind='text: DsItems'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tyler_michell,  it was a mistake... and both solution worked!

Comment: @Marisco if the solution worked for you please mark the answer as accepted so we know the question is closed.

Comment: Oops.. Thanks @Jason I forgot about it.